# Quanto Factor - FX Forward

Tags: fx, forward, currency

In the paper [Quanto Options](https://mathfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/wystup_quanto_eqf.pdf) by Uwe Wystup the "quanto factor" $Q$ is used to describe forwards/options when quanto-ed into a different currency, e.g.

$$\text{Quanto Forward Value} = Q \cdot e^{-r_Q T}\cdot \phi \cdot (S_0 \cdot e^{\tilde\mu T}-K)$$

where $K$ denotes the strike, $T$ the expiration time, $\phi=\pm1$ the usual long-short indicator, $S_0$ the underlying and $Q$ the quanto factor.

The paper never explicitly says (or at least I don't see it), what $Q$ is. Do we have something like
$$Q = e^{\rho \cdot \sigma_{1} \cdot \sigma_{2}}$$ 
?

Comment: According to the book FX Options by Wystup "A Quanto Option can be any type of cash settled option, whose payoff is converted into a third currency at maturity at a pre-specified rate called the Quanto Factor". So whereas an ordinary FX option involves 2 currencies, a Quanto Option involves 3. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

as noob2 wrote, Q is the pre-agreed on (ie fixed in advance) fx rate , ie it is the guaranteed exchange rate.
eg if your underlying were the DAX index and you wanted your payoff to be linear in the DAX, but in USD , then Q would be some constant number and it's units would be EURUSD , and so the "Quanto Forward Value" of your equation would be in USD.

PS, the "Quanto Forward Value" is a bit of an ambiguous name since it is discounted, ie it is a spot value, not forward!.  It is the Spot value (ie present value) of a forward contract.